# Working with large .JSON file (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, database, json, decode

I have a large JSON file that I'm trying to insert into a database. When using the `json_decode` to convert it to an array to insert it into the database, I get an error:

```
Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 188340087 bytes) in site.php on line 48
```

Is there a more efficient way to translate this data without having to read line by line and buffering. If not, how should I go about reading each line and decoding it? I'd appreciate any help.

```
{"items":[ {
  "itemId" : 17730521,
  "parentItemId" : 17730521,
  "name" : "1000 lb Flat-Free Super Steel P-Handle Hand Truck",
  "msrp" : 110.0,
  "salePrice" : 87.94,
  "upc" : "053417031815",
  "categoryPath" : "Home Improvement/Tools/Lifting Equipment",
  "shortDescription" : "The Flat-Free 1000-pound Heavy-Duty Hand Truck is one tough truck with its heavy-duty oversized frame, extra large base plate and curved frame back that easily transports boxes or cylinders.",
  "longDescription" : "&lt;br&gt;&lt;b&gt;1000 lb Flat-Free Super Steel P-Handle Hand Truck:&lt;/b&gt;&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;Heavy-duty flat-free 10&quot; solid rubber wheels&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;1000 lb capacity&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Extra large 20&quot; x 8&quot; base plate for bulky and oversized loads&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;50&quot; height for larger loads&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;P-loop handle for easy 1- or 2-hand control&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Large fenders to protect load from damage&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Dimensions: 50&quot;L x 21&quot;W x 19&quot;H&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;1-year warranty&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;",
  "brandName" : "Generic",
  "thumbnailImage" : "this is a link",
  "mediumImage" : "this is a link",
  "largeImage" : "this is a link",
  "productTrackingUrl" : "",
  "ninetySevenCentShipping" : false,
  "standardShipRate" : 0.0,
  "twoThreeDayShippingRate" : 79.97,
  "overnightShippingRate" : 73.97,
  "marketplace" : false,
  "shipToStore" : true,
  "freeShipToStore" : true,
  "modelNumber" : "H5986",
  "productUrl" : "",
  "categoryNode" : "1072864_1031899_1043985",
  "bundle" : false,
  "clearance" : true,
  "preOrder" : false,
  "stock" : "Available",
  "availableOnline" : true,
  "bestMarketplacePrice" : {
    "price" : 120.0,
    "sellerInfo" : "PlumStruck",
    "standardShipRate" : 5.99,
    "availableOnline" : true,
    "clearance" : false
  }
}, 
...
]}
```

Comment: got any more memory you can allocate?

Comment: I have tried allocating memory, unfortunately when loading the file its uses too much of my server resources. I'm trying to make it light weight and efficient to not hinder the memory.

Comment: What structure is this JSON array in?  What's your problem with reading it line-by-line.  If it's just an array and better yet mostly line-delimited, this is really easy.

Comment: it is a follows above. I forgot to include the structure.

Comment: Is there any way of splitting your file beforehand?

Comment: Any suggestions on how to start?

Answer (score 0):

There was a fine fellow who wrote this lib to parse large JSON
https://github.com/kuma-giyomu/JSONParser

As author says:

How:

Read the test/test.php file for a real example. But basically:

create a parser instance

set the handlers for the events you're interested in

run the parseDocument method

wait 'n see